# Getting JavaScript Error as Uncaught TypeError :cannot read property 'getContext of null

Tags: javascript

Here is the code, it just a simple animation.
The code is written after still getting this error, why is it not loading?

```
    <script>
        /**This is written outside Canvas tag, Why am I getting Uncought TypeError:cannot read property 'getContext of null**/


        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var update = function(){
            x = x + speed; 
        };

        var draw = function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,300);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,100)";
            ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        };

        var step = function(){

            update();
            draw();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);


        };
        step();

    </script>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` block is probably *before* the HTML where the canvas element appears. Thus `getElementById()` returns `null`.

Comment: Put `<canvas id=mycanvas></canvas>` before the script. In any case, [waiting for the DOM to be loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) will save you headaches in the future.

Comment: <script> is after <canvas>

Comment: Fellas i got it! Id wasnt matching, where declared Id is myCanvas and I called mycanvas